# Making the response the angle in `turtle.right()`

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make the value in `turtle.right()` the response to `response = raw_input("")`. Here is the code:

```py
print "Enter the number of degrees that you want .turtle to turn right"
choseDoor = False;
while choseDoor == False:
    response = raw_input("Some suggestions are 1300, 179, 260, 59, 6400, 9999999, 123456789, 192837465, 150, 10 = 31415926, 11 = 1919, 12 = 126789\n")
    if (response == "1") | (response == "one") | (response == "2") | (response == "two") | (response == "3") | (response == "three") | (response == "4") | (response == "four") | (response == "5") | (response == "five") | (response == "6") | (response == "six") | (response == "7") | (response == "seven") | (response == "8") | (response == "eight") | (response == "9") | (response == "nine") | (response == "10") | (response == "ten") | (response == "11") | (response == "eleven") | (response == "12") | (response == "twelve"):
        choseDoor = True
        print "this part of the script has been disabled. Please try again"
        choseDoor = False
    else:
        val = "response"
        import turtle
        turtle.shape("turtle")  
        turtle.color("brown") 
        turtle.speed(99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)   #experement with speed
        for i in range(9999999):
            turtle.forward( i +5)
            turtle.right(0 + "val")

            #this part only goes in a straight line so far.
```

My intent is to make the drawing's angle's value (`turtle.right()`) be the given response. For example, if my response was `36`, `turtle.right(36)` would be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to cast `response` to int and then you can use val in the expression. Also you can remove the toggling of `choseDoor` in the `if` as it reverts back to `False`. Because you are casting I'd recommend adding a new boolean `canCast` to see if the response can be cast as an int, then you can get rid of the long `if` expression

```
print "Enter the number of degrees that you want .turtle to turn right"
choseDoor = False
canCast=True # new boolean
while choseDoor == False:
    response = raw_input("Enter the number of degrees that you want .turtle to turn right:")
    try:
        response=int(response)
    except:
        canCast=False #can't cast response must be a string
    if not canCast:
        print "this part of the script has been disabled. Please try again"
        canCast=True #reset the canCast flag
    else:
        val = int(response) # cast response to int
        import turtle
        turtle.shape("turtle")  
        turtle.color("brown") 
        turtle.speed(99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)   #experement with speed
        for i in range(9999999):
            turtle.forward( i +5)
            turtle.right(val)
```

Answer (score 2):

Turtle angles are `float` so I've used that instead of `int` as in @depperm's solution; the `10 = 31415926, 11 = 1919, 12 = 126789` looked like predefined angles so I threw those in; I added an 'exit' option; the `turtle.speed(99999...99999)` makes no sense, only values 0 - 10 work so I switched it to the alternate `"fastest"` argument format;  `forward(9999999 + 5)` seemed excessive so I dropped it to 100; I added some logic such that two different angle inputs in a row will draw concentric objects and raise the pen inbetween:

```
import turtle

predefined = {10: 31415926, 11: 1919, 12: 126789}

print("Enter the angle in degrees that you want the turtle to turn right")

while True:
    response = raw_input("Some suggestions are 1300, 179, 260, 59, 6400, 9999999, 123456789, 192837465, 150, 10 = 31415926, 11 = 1919, 12 = 126789\n")

    if response.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    elif response in predefined:
        angle = predefined[response]
    else:
        try:
            angle = float(response)
        except ValueError:
            print("this part of the script has been disabled. Please try again")
            continue

    turtle.shape('turtle')  # do this late so open turtle window after prompts
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.color('brown')
    turtle.home() # for drawings after initial one

    turtle.pendown()

    for i in range(100):
        turtle.forward(i + 5)
        turtle.right(angle)

    turtle.penup()
```